# Infinite-dimensional algebraic objects

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be the infinite-dimensional seperable complex Hilbert space, and $P(H)$ denote its projectivization $H / \Bbb{C}^{\times}$, where $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$ acts on $H$ by multiplication. It can be seen that $P(H)$ has a rather simple topology: It is a model of $K(\Bbb{Z},2)$.
Suppose $A$ is a continuous symmetric $d$-linear function on $H$. We can then define the homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ w.r.t. $A$ as $p_A : H \rightarrow \Bbb{C} : v \mapsto A(\underbrace{v,v,...,v}_{d \text{ times}})$. The zero locus of $p_A$ is invariant under the $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$ action and has a well-defined projection onto $P(H)$. This can be seen as an analogue of finite-dimensional projective algebraic sets.
We call $p_A$ irreducible if it can not be written as the multiplication of $2$ non-constant homogeneous polynomials, and non-singular if the Fréchet derivative of $p_A$ is non-degenerate everywhere aside from the origin.

**Question**: Are there any nontrivial topological results on the common zero loci of finitely many irreducible/non-singular polynomials, such as their total homotopy groups are finitely generated (e.g. the algebraic sets of degree $1$ have homotopy type $K(\Bbb{Z},2)$)? In particular, since the unit sphere in $H$ is diffeomorphic to $H$ itself thus admits a pullback complex structure (which differs from most finite-dimensional cases), is it also realizable as an algebraic set?

**Motivation**: Low-degree (compared to the ambient space) hypersurfaces and their intersections have simpler topology (e.g. do not achieve the maximal possible Kodaira dimension) and richer symmetries (e.g. have infinite-order automorphism groups) in contrast to the high-degree generic ones. I'm wondering if every finite number is "low enough" compared to the infinity of a Hilbert space.

Comment: A better-proposed formulation can be seen [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420655/infinite-dimensional-algebraic-varieties).